# Create daemon thread

Tags: python, windows, multithreading

I'm trying to create a daemon thread under Windows, but I have no clue what am I doing wrong. The code below is acting as a normal thread: I don't see "End run" written to the console. Any suggestions?

```
def start(self):         
    self.isrunning = True        
    self.thread = threading.Thread(name="GPS Data", target=self.thread_run)
    self.thread.setDaemon(True)
    self.thread.run()
    print "End Run"


def thread_run(self):
    while self.isrunning:
        data  = self.readline()
        print(data)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following:

```
self.thread.run()
```

should read:

```
self.thread.start()
```

Otherwise, `thread_run()` is getting called in the context of the current thread, and not in the context of a new thread.

The `thread_run()` function never returns (because `self.isrunning` never changes), and the code never reaches the `print` statement.