# Print character while copying big folder

Tags: python, shutil

I have this function trying to print additional '.' every second while it's copying a big folder (~3GB) from one place to another:

```
def copy_folder(source, destination):
    print 'copying',
    while shutil.copytree(src=source, dst=destination):
        print '.',
        time.sleep(1)
```

but when I call the function:

```
source = 'source_folder'
destination = 'destination_folder'
copy_folder(source=source, destination=destination)
```

it's copying perfectly fine the whole folder but it does NOT print '.' at all.

Do I need to use threads?

Comment: Yes. you need to launch a separate thread to print the periods. See [Brianestey's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12047716/1142167).

Comment: I believe you are mistaken by the semantics of `while` statement in Python. Here is a good resource: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Threading in Python is pretty simple:

```
import sys, shutil, time, threading

class CopyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, source, destination):
        super(CopyThread, self).__init__()

        self.source = source
        self.destination = destination

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(5)  # Delete me later on, I'm just here to slow things down
        return shutil.copytree(src=self.source, dst=self.destination)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = CopyThread('source_folder', 'destination_folder')
    thread.start()

    while thread.is_alive():
        sys.stdout.write('.')
        sys.stdout.flush()

        time.sleep(1)

    thread.join()
```

Just subclass `threading.Thread` and override `run()`. After that, call `.start()` on an instance of that class and you have a thread.

Comment: +1 for `is_alive()` (no need for a separate variable), and `write()`+`flush()`.

Answer (score 1):

copytree will copy the entire tree so the while loop won't run until the copy is complete and the return value can be evaluated.

My python is rusty, but I'll give an idea of how to implement the thread (inspired by the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9096685/591801)).

```
def copy_folder(source, destination):
    self.iscopying = True        
    self.thread = threading.Thread(name="GPS Data", target=self.thread_run)
    self.thread.setDaemon(True)
    self.thread.start()
    shutil.copytree(src=source, dst=destination)
    self.iscopying = false


def thread_run(self):
    while self.iscopying:
        print '.'
        time.sleep(1)
```

Essentially, create a flag that tells the thread when the copying is happening and then set it to false when the copy is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the copytree [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/shutil.py#l145), the core of it is this loop:

```
for name in names:
   if name in ignored_names:
       continue
   srcname = os.path.join(src, name)
   dstname = os.path.join(dst, name)
   try:
       if symlinks and os.path.islink(srcname):
           linkto = os.readlink(srcname)
           os.symlink(linkto, dstname)
       elif os.path.isdir(srcname):
           copytree(srcname, dstname, symlinks, ignore)
       else:
           # Will raise a SpecialFileError for unsupported file types
           copy2(srcname, dstname)
   # catch the Error from the recursive copytree so that we can
   # continue with other files
   except Error, err:
       errors.extend(err.args[0])
   except EnvironmentError, why:
       errors.append((srcname, dstname, str(why)))
```

If you add a `yield` right at the end, your loop will work - but you would be printing after every file or directory copied, rather than at time intervals (your `time.sleep` would happen between copies, and just make the whole thing take a bit longer; for every time interval, yes you will need threads). But, this would also allow you to give more detailed feedback if you were so inclined - eg, you could `yield name` (or, `yield (srcname, destname)`) to be able to print feedback on *which* file has been copied.

Comment: +1 to make your rep not exactly 5,000. This would be pretty useful for a detailed progress bar, so thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a module to do this asynchronously... Not that there isn't one... But you could recursively go through the folder and print the "." After each file/folder